# Javascript appendChild resets scroll of other page elements in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, appendchild

I am having trouble with the scroll of divs on pages when viewed in IE, no problem in Chrome or FF
I have a div on a page which has a scroll bar (vertical) and if it has been scrolled down when I use the function appendChild to either the body or any other part of the page the scroll on the other div resets back to the top.
Please can you offer any suggestions why this might happen, perhaps something to do with redraw/reflow but why only IE?

Another thing I have noticed which may be the cause is that it only seems to happen on pages with position fixed on them.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem with a demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/) or similar?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem http://jsfiddle.net/vasek7/hvqYH/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't recreate it in it's simplest form. It's only come about as a page has become more and more complicated, I successfully use similar things all over my pages.I will try adding the individual components that make the page complicated until I recreate the problem, sorry for any time wasted, but I thought someone may have come across something similar that might save me this headache.

Comment: Ow sorry.. IE 9 & it doesn't happen in IE 8 (document mode). It might be something to do with window.attachEvent("onscroll", DoSomething) because when that doesn't work in IE 8 document mode the problem goes away.

Comment: I've spent all day isolating everything down to the bare bones, testing every step of the way.I finally nailed down the problem to a missing class declaration on a div on my page. I gave it a class name but the class didn't exist. Thanks IE, wish I could have my day back now.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 9 was finding a dead class reference on an element on my page when rendering. When it did this it was loading each element fresh again in this case without saving how far it was already scrolled down.